# How to remove an element of List<int[]> in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to program a Sudoku solver in C# in which I'm using a List of an integer array with all the positions of empty fields, because I need them in my algorithm.
In the progress of solving the Sudoku I need to remove those positions which got filled with a number. But somehow my list with empty positions does not get smaller, when I use the Remove-method.
I will explain my problem with a simplified example:

```
        List<int[]> test1 = new List<int[]>();
        test1.Add(new int[] { 0, 0 });
        test1.Add(new int[] { 1, 7 });

        test1.Remove(new int[] { 1, 7 });
```

The first line generates the list with my one dimensional integer array (which **always** consists of two values - one for the column and one for the row-number). The empty positions get added in a method, but in this example I just added them in these two lines.
Later on in my algorithm, I want to remove elements by using the Remove-function similarly to the Add-function. It throws no errors, even while compiling. However, it's not removing anything.
I tried using the RemoveAll-method, although I don't really understand, how it works and therefore didn't find a correct solution for my problem.

By trying out a List of integers (not an integer array) the Remove-method works perfectly, but in the case of an array it doesn't seem to work this way.
Even creating a seperat variable rem

```
        int[] rem = new int[] { 1, 7 };
        test1.Remove(rem);
```

does not work.
I'm a beginner so I don't really know if a List of arrays is the best solution in my case.

Comment: You're creating a new item which is a reference type. Since it's a new reference, it's not going to be evaluated as equal to the existing array in your list. You would either need to create the reference type outside of the list and then add it (so you can refer to it when you want to remove it), or use the `RemoveAt` method and specify the index you want to remove (which you can determine by your own equality algorithm)

Comment: *"It throws no errors, even while compiling. However, it's not removing anything."* If you look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-7.0) for `Remove`, you'll see that it returns a `bool` value that indicates if the item was found or not. So the behavior you're seeing is expected.

Comment: For what it';s worth, typically a grid is stored in a two-dimensional array, where the first dimension represents the `row`, and the second dimension represents the `column`. Then the value of the cell at a particular row and column is stored in the array using the row and column numbers (with `0` being the first) indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not able to remove items from your list using the `Remove` method is that you're storing reference types in the `List`, but creating *new* references when trying to remove an item. Because reference types by default use a reference comparison (not a comparison of their fields) to determine equality, you won't be able to remove items in that way.

One way to resolve this is to create a reference to each object in the `List<int[]>` *outside* of the list creation itself. This way, you can use the existing reference as an argument to the `Remove` method, and, because it's referring to the same object that was added to the list, it will match and be removed:

```
// Here we have 'item1' and 'item2' that refer to the location of different int[]
int[] item1 = new int[] { 0, 0 };
int[] item2 = new int[] { 1, 7 };

// And now we use those references to add the int[] items to our list
List<int[]> test1 = new List<int[]>();
test1.Add(item1);
test1.Add(item2);

// Finally, we can remove an item using the same reference that we used to add it
test1.Remove(item2);
```

This is very clunky, however, since we now need to maintain an individual reference for every item in our list as well as the list itself.

Another way to resolve this would be to search for the item we want to remove using our own equality algorithm (rather than relying on the default equality that `Remove` uses). We can use `FirstOrDefault` to search for the first item that has a length of 2 and whose values match those that we want. It will return a reference to the item if it's found, or `null` if it's not found. We can use `IndexOf` to get the index of the item (or `-1` if it's not found), and then pass that index to the `RemoveAt` method to remove it:

```
List<int[]> test1 = new List<int[]>();
test1.Add(new int[] { 0, 0 });
test1.Add(new int[] { 1, 7 });

int indexToRemove = test1.IndexOf(test1.FirstOrDefault(item => 
    item.Length == 2 && item[0] == 1 && item[1] == 7));

if (indexToRemove >= 0) test1.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
```

---

As you can see, what you're trying to do isn't super easy. As a suggestion to help you think about the problem in a different way, you might consider using a 2-dimensional array to store the sudoku grid. Normally we store the `row` in the first dimesion and the `column` in the second dimension:

```
int[,] grid = new int[9, 9];
```

You could potentially create a few of these, one to represent the puzzle solution, one to represent the puzzle shown to the user's (with just their guesses), maybe even one to store user's "notes" (if you allow them to tag a cell with possible values before committing to a guess), though that would likely need to be a `string[,]` or an `int[,][]`.

Then the typical way to loop through the grid would be something like:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
        // Do something with the cell at 'row' 'col' here

        // Set a value for this cell
        grid[row, col] = row + col;

        // Report the value of a cell
        Console.WriteLine($"The value at row {row} and column {col} is {grid[row, col]}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IntArrayPredicate(int[] element)
{
    return element.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 2, 3 });
}

List<int[]> listOfIntArray = new List<int[]>();

listOfIntArray.Add(new int[] { 0, 0 });
listOfIntArray.Add(new int[] { 1, 7 });
listOfIntArray.Add(new int[] { 2, 3 });

listOfIntArray.RemoveAll(element => element.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 1, 7 })); //It Works!. Using lambda expresion. Remove by Comparing sequences that match equals.

int[] toRemove = listOfIntArray[0];
listOfIntArray.Remove(toRemove); //It works!. Remove element by exact reference.

listOfIntArray.Remove(new int[] { 2, 3 }); // Not working / References are different.

listOfIntArray.RemoveAll(IntArrayPredicate); // It works!. Same as using lambda but using method reference.
            
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(listOfIntArray)} has {listOfIntArray.Count()} elements"); // Yup. 0 elements.
```